# Alternate citation with Org-Ref

Tags: org-mode, org-link, org-ref

I am used to manage my bibliography  with org-ref and I am very satisfy with it. Nevertheless, in the context of a grant proposal writing, space is limited. So I would to save the space allowed to bibliography refs by replacing the classical citation approach by direct links on DOI (through https:\\doi.org...) of the cited paper. 
i.e. something like:

```
[[https://www.doi.org/10.1002/jbio.200900094][Sim2017]]
```

instead of :

```
cite:sim2017
```

Do you know if is there a way to do what I expect  with org-ref ?  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `(org-ref-define-citation-link "citea")` to your init file, and it should create that link type.

Comment: I just copied @JohnKitchin's comment into a community wiki answer, so we could get an upvoted answer and take this question off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution first rests in Latex instead of the org-ref configuration. Indeed a solution using biblatex and the definition of a new command is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438338/can-i-use-citeurl-inside-href) by [Yegor256](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1449/yegor256) and perfectly do the job (but directly in Latex). 
Now the next step is to make org-ref able to recognize this alternate `\citea{}` command. Any idea ?

Comment: I think you can just add (org-ref-define-citation-link "citea") to your init file, and it should create that link type.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly ! The last thing I have to do is to create a keyboard shortcut in helm.